# Unable to Access a deployed app(Airflow) on Rancher (RKE) hosted locally on Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, rancher

I have pulled rancher image on docker, and I deployed Apache Airflow on the local RKE Cluster on Rancher, but I cannot access airflow using ingress or Load balancer.

I am using the Kubernetes local-cluster created by Rancher.

Update: I am Using Rancher 2.5.5

Docker Desktop : v20.10.2

Kubelet Version: v1.18.8+k3s1

Containerd Version: 1.3.3-k3s2

Kube Proxy Version: v1.18.8+k3s1

I am not facing any error, I am just can't expose the service to the host Ip to be accessed through network.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide which version of docker and rkt have you installed and logs of error encountered.

Comment: @hdhruna Updated , but I am not facing any error all the  deployed components are active and deployed successfully , but i can't open the deployed app from the UI